# I want to find all the ids of employee which are selected by toggle button in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.toggleSelection = function($index) {
     var idx = $scope.employees[$index].id;

     var result = $.grep($scope.selection, function(e){ return e.id == idx; });
     var flg=true;
     var x=0;
     for ( var i=0; i<$scope.selection.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.selection[i].id == idx){ 
            flg = false;x=i;
            break;
            }

      }
      if(flg){
        $scope.selection.insert($scope.selection.length,$scope.employees[$index]);

      }else{
        $scope.selection.remove(x);
      }

   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `$index` with `ng-repeat` because you will have bugs when you will try to remove items from the array. Use the employee id, `ng-repeat="employee in employees track by employee.id`

And pls give some more info about what you want to achieve.